# Trying to use the ocaml-mm library

Tags: terminal, ocaml, libraries, opam

I'm trying to use the ocaml-mm package (https://github.com/savonet/ocaml-mm) and trying to run one of the examples for sine_wav.ml

I first installed the package and also installed the ao library, which the sine_wav file uses. Everything compiles, but I get this error when I'm trying to run the file:

```
ddavidjeong@DESKTOP-60PESIS:~/cs3110/ms/test$ make main
Entering directory '/home/ddavidjeong/cs3110/ms'
Fatal error: exception Failure("Failed to open device")
make: *** [Makefile:2: main] Error 2
ddavidjeong@DESKTOP-60PESIS:~/cs3110/ms/test$
```

I have no idea what this exception could refer to.

Comment: I don't know dune, but the error suggests you're trying to execute a source file. This suggests you have a source file listed where an executable (compiled and linked) file should go.

Comment: source file? I have a main ocaml file with the code and a dune file with the executable. Those are the only files in the directory. It's strange because one of my other friends pulled pretty much the same thing on their laptop and it runs fine.

Comment: The second error message has since been deleted, but it showed a failing attempt to run a ".ml" file as if it were executable.

Comment: "Failed to open device" suggests you're trying to access a bit of hardware, maybe a sound card? You might try an external test program to see if you can generate audio (which I assume is what you're trying to do).

Comment: yeah sorry, the second error message was because I was using the wrong dune command. How would I try an external test program? The file I'm running, when called, should be generating and outputting audio. I'm a little lost because this was an example file that was listed in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

This errors means that the libao library failed to open its default audio device. You can at least check which default device was found by the library by using in utop

````ml
#require "ao";;
Ao.get_default_driver ()
```ocaml
Similarly, you can get the list of all audio device found by libao with
```ocaml
Ao.drivers;;
````

If there is no visible issue with the default driver, and there is some non-default driver available that looks like they might work; it would be possible to try to use another device in sin_wave.ml by replacing the instance of the `Mm_ao.writer` class in

```
 let ao = new Mm_ao.writer channels sample_rate in
```

by an instance of

```
class ao_writer driver channels rate = object
 object
    val dev = Ao.open_live ~driver ~channels ~rate ~byte_format:`LITTLE_ENDIAN ()

    method write buf ofs len =
      let s = Audio.S16LE.make buf ofs len in
      Ao.play dev s

    method close = Ao.close dev
  end
```

with the right driver.
But it is probably better to see why `libao` cannot open the default device that it selected itself.